# Set JavaFX table column name padding

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to reduce the size of the padding arround the column name:

I tested this code:

```
.table-view .column-header{
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
    -fx-font-size: 10;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
}
```

But with this css code I can only set the size of the text font. But I cannot the padding arround the text. Can you tell me how I can do this?

Comment: If you set overflow: hidden on your div, you may see this behaviour stop. Of course, you probably don't want this; you may be better off trying to manually set the height of those table elements, and ensure that they have margin: 0 set.

Comment: Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
.table-view .column-header{
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
    -fx-font-size: 10;
    -fx-size: 11 ;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
}
```

Comment: you can also use `-fx-padding: -1 -1 -1 -1;` in that css